# Lost access to DCIM/SUBDIR in Android 10

Tags: android, permission-denied, android-10.0, storage-access-framework

My application writes files to `DCIM/SUBDIR` like camera does. It was working fine before Android 10. Now it doesn't see the contents of this directory and produces

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/SUBDIR/myfile: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

How to overcome? I can't allow user to select file, because my workflow is like in camera: you are not selecting filename on each picture taken. So I probably can't use [`Storage Access Framework`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider)?

Comment: You can use the MediaStore to write files to a subdir of DCIM. Also SAF is usable once the user choosed the DCIM directory.

Comment: @blackapps I never choosed `DCIM` directory for Camera app, I need the same. I am writing to a file from within native code, can I use `MediaStore` in the case?

Comment: Sorry, i dont know. Can you use SAF?

Comment: I don't want to bother the used. Push and go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add below key in `<application>` tag of `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

File access in Android 10 is based `scoped storage` standard.

Please [check this out](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/use-cases)

This will work only for Android 10. It will not work if you set target version to 11. [Check this.](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/use-cases#opt-out-scoped-storage)

Comment: Can I fix in 11 too?

Comment: In Android 11. I didnt know much about it but as per documentation you need migration see this link: https://developer.android.com/preview/privacy/storage#migrate-data-for-scoped-storage

Comment: `Can I fix in 11 too?` No need to fix. The directory is usable again then.